# how visualstudio knows about the type of current project?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, project, solution

In Visual Studio, the context menu command for adding an element in a WinForms project is different by the one showed for a WPF project. In fact, I can see "Add->Windows Form" in the first and "Add->Window" in the second. By which parameter/configuration VisualStudio can differentiate which kind of project is currently opened? My first bet was the .csproj file but I can see nothing distinctive about the project type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is often a `ProjectTypeGuids` element in the project file that allows Visual Studio to determine what project type it is. It's also stated in the solution file, referencing the project.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

as an example.

Here's a somewhat old link to a list of project guids, but most are still valid: http://onlinecoder.blogspot.se/2009/09/visual-studio-projects-project-type.html

And here's a blogpost, outlining what it's all about:

> http://www.dzimchuk.net/blog/post/ProjectTypeGuids-node-in-VS-project-files.aspx
>
> "On a regular class library project the ‘ProjectTypeGuids’ node was missing at all. It didn’t take long to find what those mysterious GUID’s are about: [List of known project type Guids](http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx). So the first one says it’s a WPF project and the second one says it’s a C# project."

Answer (score 4):

`ProjectTypeGuids` identify the type of project that Visual Studio recognizes. It is contained in the project file and solution file. A project can belong to multiple project types such as C# and VSTO.

**WPF** has a GUID of `{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548}` while **WinForms** has a GUID of `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` with [OutputType `WinExe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/924764/175679).

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a GUID in the `.sln` file that identifies the project type.

```
Project("{PROJECT-TYPE-GUID}") = "OurSolution.Tests.Integration", "OurSolution.Tests.Integration\OurSolution.Tests.Integration.csproj", "{04A96D9A-FF90-4FDC-9265-704CC8D496BE}"
```

Comment: While, yes, it's in the solution file as well, it's originally in the proj-file if it's anything but a class library. Otherwise it'd be damned difficult to import a project into another solution. =)

Comment: @J. Steen Thank you, didn't know that. I wonder what receives priority when loading using a solution.

Comment: I'd assume the solution file, considering it loads first - but I'm far from certain - so I guess the _actual_ answer to the question "how does VS know" would be, as you've said: the solution file. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Almost right, it's in the solution file. Search for the property ProjectTypeGuids.

Here's a list of some GUID's for project types:
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx

Edit: see this post for answers as well: [How do you tell the Visual Studio project type from an existing Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660790/how-do-you-tell-the-visual-studio-project-type-from-an-existing-visual-studio-pr)